# Is this Function Continuous Piecewise

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$f: [0,1] \cup [3,4] \rightarrow \mathbb R $ given by $f(x)=x$. Is this continuous on its domain?

I know it's continuous at $[0,1) \cup (3,4]$. Am I right in assuming that it is also continuous at $x=1$ and $x=3$.

I know $f$ will be continuous if $f(1)=1$ is equal to the limit as $x$ tends to $1$ of $f(x)$. Since $f$ is not defined between $x=1$ and $x=3$, I am not sure if this is true or not, as I don't understand how the right hand limit as $x$ approaches $1$ can be defined.

Comment: Ignore me I'm being stupid, can this be deleted please? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot approach $x=1$ from the right hand side, so only by left.